# Alternatives to az login for deploying using azure-cli docker container

Tags: azure-devops, azure-cli

I am using the following scripts to deploy to azure (simplified for question)

deploy.sh:

```
docker run -v $(pwd):/app mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli sh -c "./app/upload-to-azure.sh"
```

upload-to-azure.sh

```
az login
az storage blob upload-batch --source /app/build --destination \$web --account-name mystorageaccount --subscription 1234
```

The use of az login command requires me to login through a web browser to microsoft's devicelogin page and use a code.

What other options are there for authenticating that are suitable for a ci pipeline using the azure-cli docker container?

Comment: Hi, how the things going? Does the below command can help you avoid the browser loading? Feel free to share with us whether it is works:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it has.

Please try with:

```
az login -u {user account} -p {password}
```

[image]

This method can let you login directly, and will not load the web browser to let you login.

Comment: Getting the following when I try the above:

Authentication failed due to error of 'Unsupported wstrust endpoint version. Current support version is wstrust2005 or wstrust13.' This typically happens when attempting a Microsoft account, which requires interactive login. Please invoke 'az login' to cross check. More details are available at https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/wiki/Username-Password-Authentication